# SMS getting received after a long delay (using SIMCOM SIM900A and Raspberry Pi 4)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sms, at-command, sim900

I am trying to read messages from sim900a as they get received and filter them to get the required messages. But most of the times the message are getting delayed (10-60 min). I need the delay to be as minimum as possible.

The AT commands I am using to initialize the connection are:

```
ATZ

AT+CMGF=1

AT+CSDH=1

AT+CLTS=1

AT+CPMS="SM","SM","SM"

AT+CNMI=1,1,0,0,0

AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"

AT+CSAS
```

And to read messages I am using

```
AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"
```

I have used different and same carrier sims but the delay largely remains same (slightly reduced in case of same carriers). I used the sims in two mobile phones and the messages are received almost instantly.

Comment: Do you mean the messages are not sent instantly? In that case I'm afraid that's very little you can do about it, as the time is managed by your network operator (I don't know if you can change it).

Comment: The messages are received instantly when the sim is in a mobile phone but when the sim is in gsm module, most of the times there is a delay in receipt of sms.

Comment: I assume you perform the tests on the phone and and on the module usinf the same SIM. Am I correct? How do you measure the reception time? How doy you read from the module? 10-60 minutes delay sounds to me too much even with a suboptimal reading script.

Comment: Yes I performed the same test on phone and gsm module. I am constantly polling for any sms received using AT+CMGL=ALL. I am basiclally taking the time at which Pi is getting the sms as reception time.

Comment: SM memory full? Please, reproduce the issue (you don't receive the message) then issue `AT+CPMS?` and come back here with the answer.

Comment: I delete the messages once they are read, I have set AT+CPMS = "SM","SM","SM", during initialization.

Comment: The write command you send at init time sets the preferred memory storage. The read command I suggested you contains also the number of messages actually stored in a specific moment.

Comment: But if the memory is full wouldn't it just fetch all of them when I do AT+CMGL=ALL. But in my logs there is nothing. Anyways I will try it.

Comment: You are correct. But if the network is fast (and you verified it by testing the same SIM in a mobile phone), and excluding things like bugs in the module or signal coverage (that would make deregister the device) the reason of the delay must be something like that.

Comment: Both `AT+CMGL=\"ALL` and `AT+CSCS=\"GSM` missing the closing `\"`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Sorry for the late response. But this is what i got: AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: "SM",0,10,"SM",0,10,"SM",0,10

Comment: @hcheung Sorry I missed them here, it is fine in code.

Comment: 0 messages currently stored... So you confirm that the antenna is correctly connected, and it is placed where a good level of signal is received? Otherwise the slowness of device appears to me as the only possibility missing..